# Combine listitems Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, listitem

I was wondering if there is a standard function to combine/merge all elements from a list.
I can't seem to find one.

So for example:

```
combine["abc","def"] should result in ["abcdef"]
```

Comment: Do you want it to return `["abcdef"]` or `"abcdef"`?

Comment: What you're looking for is concat.

Answer (score 2):

[Let me Hoogle that for you](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=[[a]]+-%3E+[a])...

More generally, the concept of "combining", "merging", is captured by the [`Monoid`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-Monoid.html) class<sup>1</sup>. It has both a `mappend` function, for combining two values, and `mconcat` for flattening a whole list.

---

<sup>1</sup>Actually, [`Semigroup`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/semigroups) is enough... provided the list isn't empty.

Comment: Would you like to include foldl and foldr too?

Comment: I found a solution guys. Thanks for the help.

replicate 1 (concat["abc","def"])

Comment: @Pidaji: `replicate 1` sure works, but isn't exactly to the point. _Why_ do you need the outer list at all, if it contains only one element? If you really have a good reason, just use `[concat ["abc", "def"]]`. (Alternatively, `(:[]) $ concat ["abc", "def"]` or `return $ concat ["abc", "def"]`.